# onclick event on multiple causes to trigger always the first div-JS/REACTJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 div on which I have an onclick event.

js:

```
<div>
 <div class="test" onClick={this.getTest.bind(id)}><a>delete</a></div>
 <div class="test2" onClick={this.getTest2.bind(query)}></div>
</div>

getTest(id) {
  //some code
}

getTest2(query) {
  //some code
}
```

now for some reason when I click on second div with class="test2", it always goes into the first div by default, and I checked the `event.target`, it always includes the first div target clicked. I also tried applying the `onclick` on the `<a>` tag, but still the same.I dont understand how can I prevnet this from happening. Any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, you are not `binding` the `event` properly, use these `click` events:

```
onClick={this.getTest.bind(this,id)}

onClick={this.getTest2.bind(this,query)}
```

Check the working code:

```js
class App extends React.Component{

   getTest(id){console.log('div1', id)}
   
   getTest2(id){console.log('div2', id)}

   render(){   
       return(       
            <div>
                <div class="test" onClick={this.getTest.bind(this, '1')}><a>Div 1</a></div>
                <div class="test2" onClick={this.getTest2.bind(this, '2')}>Div 2</div>
            </div>       
       )   
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id ='app'/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your `onClick` event to `{this.getTest.bind(this)}` and see if that makes a difference.  You also want to make sure your `getTest(id)` and `getTest2(query)` methods are placed before your `render()` method.